# Change title using jquery?

Tags: jquery, append, title

I have this Jquery that I change active link on page, checking a href and adding class active

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var uri = String(window.location.href).replace(/#/, "");
    $(".main-navigation ul li a").filter(function () {
        return (this.href == uri || uri.substr(0, this.href.length + 1) == this.href + "?");
    }).css({
        'color': '#666666',
        'font-weight': 'bold',
    }).addClass('active').removeAttr("href").removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

What i need is to add

```
$('title').html(title);
```

To get that a href text and add title to page, how to extend that function?

**Change title of the document by text in active link**

**UPDATE**

```
  var str = $("a.active").text();
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    $("title").html(str);
```

Comment: The title tag's HTML is readily available like this. Can you be clearer about what you're trying to do? Are you trying to create links to *other* pages?

Comment: Now i want to get current active link get a text from a href and display in title of element

Comment: It is still very unclear what you are trying to do? Do you want to change the title of the active link? Or change the title of the page to the active link?

Comment: Change title of what?

Comment: Change title of the document by text in active link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the title of the page to the text of a link with the class `active`. you can use the following

```
$("title").html($("a.active").html());
```

If the link text is within a span

```
$("title").html($("a.active span").html());
```

Comment: Because i have here like <span> can this be trimed?

Comment: you can add that to the jQuery selector. See my edit

Comment: Txanks this is close, i have just modified fro frist uppercase letter like this    var str = $("a.active").text();
    str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });
    $("title").html(str);